# Sync the current route and state of a component using react router dom

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

Is there a way to sync the active route in the browser with the state of a component?

When I click on "Route 2" in the navbar, the element is highlighted because it is the active route, and the route in the browser shows `"/route2"`. If I refresh the browser, "Route 1" is now highlighted because it is initial state of the `Navbar` component, but the route in the browser still shows `"/route2"`. Is there a way to sync the two?

To replicate the project, create a new `vite` project with `react-ts`, then add the following files:

App.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route, Navigate, Link, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { type ClassValue, clsx } from "clsx";
import { twMerge } from "tailwind-merge";

function cn(...inputs: ClassValue[]) {
  return twMerge(clsx(inputs));
}
```

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-between items-center sticky top-0 border-b bg-background px-4 h-12 z-10">
      <h1>App Name</h1>
      <div className="flex gap-4 h-8 items-center">
        <Link to="/route1" onClick={() => setSelected(0)}>
          <h2
            className={cn(
              "hover:underline hover:text-blue-500",
              selected === 0 ? "text-blue-500" : null
            )}
          >
            Route 1
          </h2>
        </Link>
        <Link to="route2" onClick={() => setSelected(1)}>
          <h2
            className={cn(
              "hover:underline hover:text-blue-500",
              selected === 1 ? "text-blue-500" : null
            )}
          >
            Route 2
          </h2>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="px-2 py-4">
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
const CompA = () => {
  return <div>Component A</div>;
};

const CompB = () => {
  return <div>Component B</div>;
};
```

```
const Route1 = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
      <div className="flex justify-center">
        <Link to="/route1/a">
          <h2 className="border p-2 hover:bg-gray-200">Component A</h2>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/route1/b">
          <h2 className="border p-2 hover:bg-gray-200">Component B</h2>
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="border">
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Route2 = () => {
  return <div>Route2</div>;
};
```

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
        <Route index element={<Navigate to="/route1" replace />} />
        <Route path="route1" element={<Route1 />}>
          <Route index element={<Navigate to="/route1/a" replace />} />
          <Route path="a" element={<CompA />} />
          <Route path="b" element={<CompB />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="route2" element={<Route2 />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "nested-routes",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "clsx": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.18.0",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.31",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.5",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  }
}
```

tailwind.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ["index.html", "./src/**/*.tsx"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

postcss.config.js

```js
export default {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

main.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.tsx'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

index.css

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Lastly, remove contents of *App.css*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the base `Link` component and manually computing the active route/link, use the [`NavLink`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link#navlink) component that handles this automatically. The `NavLink`'s [`children`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link#children) prop can take a render function prop value that is passed an `isActive` prop to be used to conditionally apply UI logic in the wrapped children UI.

> ```
> <NavLink to="/tasks">
>   {({ isActive, isPending, isTransitioning }) => (
>     <span className={isActive ? "active" : ""}>Tasks</span>
>   )}
> </NavLink>
> ```

Example:

```
...
import {
  Routes,
  Route,
  Navigate,
  NavLink,
  Outlet
} from "react-router-dom";
...

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-between items-center sticky top-0 border-b bg-background px-4 h-12 z-10">
      <h1>App Name</h1>
      <div className="flex gap-4 h-8 items-center">
        <NavLink to="/route1">
          {({ isActive }) => (
            <h2
              className={cn(
                "hover:underline hover:text-blue-500",
                isActive ? "text-blue-500" : null
              )}
            >
              Route 1
            </h2>
          )}
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink to="route2">
          {({ isActive }) => (
            <h2
              className={cn(
                "hover:underline hover:text-blue-500",
                isActive ? "text-blue-500" : null
              )}
            >
              Route 2
            </h2>
          )}
        </NavLink>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```